# Identifying Connection State of Azure Site-to-Site v2 VPN tunnels provisioned via Resource Manager

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-virtual-network, azure-vpn

Using Azure Resource Manger, I have two separate azure subscriptions (one subscription called Dev & one called UAT), and I have created a Virtual Network, with the necessary Virtual Network Gateways & Local networks in each of these subscriptions, and am attempting to connect them via a v2 Site-to-Site VPN tunnel. I was roughly following the guidelines outlined here:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-create-site-to-site-rm-powershell/

I was able to sucessfully iniatiate the connection from each direction, but as the article in the link above calls out ". At this time, the site-to-site VPN connections created with Resource Manager are not visible in the Portal."

Does anyone have any ideas on how to check the status of the V2 Gateway in the Azure tunnel.

Please keep in mind I am referring to the new (summer 2015) Virtual Networks with the Resource Mangager Gateway - not the classic gateways.

Answer (score 0):

When you wrote "V2 gateway" do you mean 2nd generation gateway?. Alternatively should Azure portal doesn't give you the status of your connection,  I suggest you check your connection status using https://resources.azure.com/. Navigate to your subscription > resource group > providers > Networks > connections. Pick your connection on the list and you will see
"

```
"connectionStatus": "Connected",
    "ingressBytesTransferred": 0,
    "egressBytesTransferred": 0,
```

"